# list view from database

Tags: android, listview

I am using database in my application,in that i have fetched data from database,but i dont know how to display it in the textview.

Here is my code:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.report);   
     db.open();
     Cursor c = db.getAllTitles();
     startManagingCursor(c);
     String[] from = new String[] { db.KEY_INCOME };
     int[] to = new int[] { R.id.textView1 };
     SimpleCursorAdapter notes =
                new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.report, c, from, to);
```

Here the notes have the database value.But don't know how to proceed how to display it in listview.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find your listview and set your adapter.  (Assuming you are not using a ListActivity)

```
ListView list = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.yourlistview);
list.setAdapter(notes);
```

If you are using a ListActivity (or ListFragment), it's even simpler as the framework assumes you are using a certain id and you can just set the adapter like so:

```
setListAdapter(notes);
```

Answer (score 0):

do like this

```
String[] titles= new String[] {c.TITLE };

        int[] view = new int[] { R.id.textview };     

        SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_example_entry, c, titles, view );
```

listview.setAdapter(notes);

Answer (score 0):

if you want to set set Tesxt on list item click you can do iy like

```
@Override
        protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            Cursor c = (Cursor) arg0.getAdapter().getItem(arg2);


tv.setTextt(c.getString(1));

    }
```